# Stop function doesn't work using progressbar

Tags: python, tkinter, progress-bar

I'm writing a program in tkinter using Progressbar. But there is a problem when I added stop function it doesn't work. When I press "stop" button nothing happens, it should stop loading progressbar. I use Python version 3.8. The code below:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import time
root = Tk()
def run():
    pb['maximum']=100
    for i in range(101):
        time.sleep(0.05)
        pb['value']=i
        pb.update()
def stop():
    pb.stop()
runbutt = Button(root,text="Runprogr",command=run)
runbutt.pack()
stopbutt = Button(root,text="Stopbut",command=stop)
stopbutt.pack()
pb = ttk.Progressbar(root,length=300,orient="horizontal")
pb.pack()
root.geometry("300x300")
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause is that `pb.stop` couldn't stop the function in `run`.it will also increase by itself.

You could use `.after(ms, callback)` to add the value(then you no longer need to use `time.sleep()`).

If you want to stop it,use `.after_cancel()`:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import time

root = Tk()
root.add_value = None

def run():
    def add():
        if pb['value'] >= 100:
            return
        pb['value'] += 1
        root.add_value = root.after(50, add)
    if root.add_value: # to prevent increasing the speed when user pressed "Runprogr" many times.
        return

    root.add_value = root.after(50, add)


def stop():
    if not root.add_value: # to prevent raising Exception when user pressed "Stopbut" button many times.
        return
    root.after_cancel(root.add_value)
    root.add_value = None


runbutt = Button(root, text="Runprogr", command=run)
runbutt.pack()
stopbutt = Button(root, text="Stopbut", command=stop)
stopbutt.pack()
pb = ttk.Progressbar(root, length=300, orient="horizontal")
pb.pack()
root.geometry("300x300")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hello I would have a question to you.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/4BkeumLe It doesn't work. I know it's not the topic of question above. But I'm out of asking quetions. Could you look at this code and would you tell me what I should correct.  It's about partial searching.

Comment: in tkinter treeview

Comment: @RObertos12 I recommend you ask a new question,what's the variable `names` in your code?

Comment: I tried somehow to pass values to var "names" after I press button add but it's error names its not defined. I tried to rewrite this code in different ways but every time I failed.

Comment: and the variable names was used in a function command and I tried to do sth like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46176129/searching-in-treeview-and-highlight-select-the-row-that-contains-the-item-that-i but it fails.

Comment: @RObertos12 You should ask a new question and add more details about that.I shouldn't post an irrelevant answer in this question.Or it would be deleted by reviewers soon.

Comment: Could you please look at the question I posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63081330/dateexpiry-products-in-tkinter-python It'about date expiry function. I don't know what to start with. Maybe you will have some idea