# How to display elements in alphabetically order ins SQLite3

Tags: sqlite, tkinter, sql-order-by

I want to display my records in alphabetically order using SQLite3 statement:

`SELECT * FROM medicine ORDER BY name ASC`

but..

```
1) It display records like this for example: 
ADRENALINE 
BETALOC 
CAPTORIL
……
Adrenaline
Betaloc
Captopril
……
adrenaline
betaloc
captopril
…..
2) But I want that sqlite3 displays like this:
ADRENALINE
Adrenaline
adrenaline
………
BETALOC
Betaloc
betaloc
………
CAPTOPRIL
Captopril
captopril
………….
```

How to write it statement that it displays like In the second case I know that upper letter have the priority but I think it’s a way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `COLLATE NOCASE` clause in `ORDER BY` so the sorting is case insensitive:

```
SELECT * 
FROM medicine 
ORDER BY name COLLATE NOCASE ASC
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qifuLodmUWvgJALkpQFKSU/1).
Results:

```
| name       |
| ---------- |
| ADRENALINE |
| Adrenaline |
| adrenaline |
| BETALOC    |
| Betaloc    |
| betaloc    |
| CAPTOPRIL  |
| Captopril  |
| captopril  |
```